# hibernate saving enum and retrieve values?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have enum as below.

```
public enum TestEnum { EXAMPLE, FURTHER_EXAMPLE, LAST_EXAMPLE }
```

With this mapping in the .hbm:

```
<property name="testEnum" column="TEST_COLUMN">
    <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
        <param name="enumClass">p.a.c.k.TestEnum</param>
    </type>
 </property>
```

The enum is sent to the database as 0, 1, 2. it is fine. but when i retrieve same results i need to get EXAMPLE, FURTHER_EXAMPLE, LAST_EXAMPLE instead of 0,1,2. how can i do that?
Please help me!

Comment: can you give the source code of your model class? I want to know what type of field you are using to store the enum value in your model

Comment: do you want to get the values from the enum by their positions in the enum?

Comment: i have below field in the model class: private TestEnum testEnum

Comment: @Waqas, yes u r right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your answer in reply of my comment.

You want to access the enum value by enum ordinal. If this is so, you can use the below code.

```
TestEnum value = TestEnum.values()[ordinal]
//ordinal can be the position that you are talking about.
```

If this is not what you want, forget about my answer, if this is what you were looking for, +1 it.